# How to get data value from UI and then use it in action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI MVC. In one page, I have a grid, a treeview and a button. When the button is clicked, I need to use the selected value in the treeview and grid to do some calculation in action, and then popup a modal window to show the results in a grid.

I can get the selected value using javascript, but how can I pass the values to an action to do calculation? and then load the grid in the popup window?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've actually tried?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a example of showing a popop using javascript.. The "NameFucntion is the function where you got the id, then pass it to a controller mvc action..

Create a partial view with the grid and populate them with a model that will be returned by that mvc action with a model.

```
 <div id="modal"></div> 
<script>
   function ShowPopup(data) {

    $("#modal").append("<div id='modal-content'></div>");

    $("#modal-content").html("<div style='width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center'><img src='http://preloaders.net/preloaders/728/Skype%20balls%20loader.gif' style='top:295px;position:relative;' /></div>");

    var dialogDiv = $("#modal-content").dialog({
        title: "Filtro Paragens",
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        width: '50%',
        minHeight: '638',
        open: function (event, ui) {

            $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').hide();
            $("#modal-content").html(data);

        }
    });

    dialogDiv = $("#modal-content").dialog("open");
}   

 function NameFunction(id){

  $.ajax({  
         cache: false,
         type: 'GET',
         data: { Id: id },
         contentType: "application/json",
         url: "Controller/Action",
         success: function (data) {
             ShowPopup(data);
         },
         fail: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
             alert("Ocorreu um erro: " + textStatus);

         }
     });
 }}


    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Action(int Id)
    {
```

List model = new List();

//do your stufs

```
        return PartialView("_PageGrid", model);
    }
```

In the _PageGrid partial, use a kendo grid example that is populated with your model.
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding

So in resume, you have a action that will return html code to the popup. (btw this use the dialog of jquery)